# How to pass special characters as query parameter guzzle

Tags: php, laravel, slim, guzzle, guzzle6

Here is my code:

the page[size] and page[number] those not work. I know its because of the special characters []. But I don't know how to resolve this. Please help

```
$client = new Client()
try{
        $response = $client->request('GET', getenv('URL').self::$propertyUrl, [
            'query' => [
                'api_key' => getenv('MTC_API_KEY'),
                'page[size]' => $pageSize,
                'page[number]' => $pageNumber
            ],
            'verify' => false
        ]);
    }catch (BadResponseException $exception){
        $response = $exception->getResponse();
    }
```

Comment: Does it work if you pass them as a proper associative array? `'page' => ['size' => $pageSize, 'number' => $pageNumber]`?

Comment: This doesn't work @TimLewis

Comment: Guys please help. I can't find any solution

Comment: Have you tried to build the query string with `http_build_query` instead?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the problem was with string concatenation between getenv('URL') and self::$propertyUrl. The self::$propertyUrl contained / slash at beginning so did getenv('URL')